# Incoming email in SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

How to configure incoming email in SharePoint 2010. I did follow some articles on technet but did not get any clear idea. Can someone explain on how to do it.
Thanks

Comment: There are just two options to fill. What is not clea in it?

Comment: Post links to the articles you mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

http://sharepointgeorge.com/2010/configuring-incoming-email-sharepoint-2010/